# Mounting azure blob to VM

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to mount an azure blob with a Linux VM and I am successfully able to do it with the storage access key. Is there any other route to do the mount? Maybe using the SAS token or AD authentication. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what tool do you use to mount? are we talking about Linux or Windows?

Comment: I have edited my question. Linux it is.

Comment: ok, but how are you mounting (successfully) with the access key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using blobfuse and you want to mount a blob/container via SAS token, pls try the steps below:

1. create a connection.cfg file with content as official doc indicated: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/blob/master/connection.cfg

in my case :
[image]

2. Run mount command:

   *blobfuse /<-the path you want to mount-> --tmp-path=/mnt/blobfusetmp
   -o attr_timeout=240 -o entry_timeout=240 -o negative_timeout=120 --config-file=<-path of your connection.cfg file-> --log-level=LOG_DEBUG --file-cache-timeout-in-seconds=120*

In my case:

```
blobfuse /testcontainer --tmp-path=/mnt/blobfusetmp -o attr_timeout=240 -o entry_timeout=240 -o negative_timeout=120 --config-file=../connection.cfg --log-level=LOG_DEBUG --file-cache-timeout-in-seconds=120
```

As you can see I mounted a container which named: `testcontainer`, and there is only one file in this container:
[image]

And this is the result of mount command:

[image]

Let me know if it works as excepted or if you need any more assistances.

Comment: Hey. Awesome. It worked. Thank you so much.  But just one issue when I upload a file in the blob, I can see it in the mounted folder in the VM but when I create a file in the VM I am not able to see it in the blob. Any idea? Basically, anything I do in the VM is not getting impacted in the blob.

Comment: Hi @Aiswarya, thanks for your reply. For your other questions, could you pls raise another question? Basically, it's one question one case here, thanks!